# "how to create event handler for restart apache service"

Tags: event-handling, nagios

I want to create Nagios core event handler whenever I stop apache service
Nagios log is generating and seems like it invoking event handler script, but is not executing it.

I am following [these](https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/3/en/eventhandlers.html) documents.

This is logs of nagios:

```
SERVICE ALERT: tecmint;HTTP load;CRITICAL;HARD;4;connect to address <ip> and port 80: Connection refused
[1607493385] SERVICE EVENT HANDLER: tecmint;HTTP load;CRITICAL;HARD;4;restart-httpd
```

Why Apache is not starting?

Comment: Try to `su` to the user running Nagios and run the event handler script manually. My guess would be that it fails due to that user not having sudo permissions to restart the service.

Comment: using  ./restart_httpd CRITICAL HARD 4 command it is restarting apache service but in local server itself not on the remote server.

Comment: Yes? What else would you expect?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to monitor and restart Apache in a remote server then you need to use SSH or NRPE with NRPE is preferred in this case as it is faster and doesn't require SSH kay pair exchange.

Briefly you would have 1 master Nagios server and 1 or more Nagios agent(s)

The master would run check_nrpe with some arguments to ask agent to check a service and optionally run an event handler (script)
like that

```
/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe -H agent_IP_Address -c command
```

where  is something like check_http which will be installed in Agent as a plugin

Master should have Nagios core installed

Agent should have NRPE agent and libexec installed
as in this manual:
https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagiosxi/docs/Installing_The_XI_Linux_Agent.pdf

Command, Hosts, and Services definitions will stay in the master

The script that restart Apache (the event handler) should be in the agent

This is a full reference of how to install and configure NRPE master-agent model
https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nrpe/NRPE.pdf?__hstc=118811158.538bdb251b7c177fd3206bea46d0e972.1616532961907.1616532961907.1616532961907.1&__hssc=118811158.11.1616532961908&__hsfp=2505829642